# Java: Find out whether function was called with varargs or array

Tags: java, variadic-functions

Is there a way to find out whether a Java function (or a constructor) that takes varargs was actually called with varargs or with an array?

Say I have the following:

```
public class MyCompositeObjects {

    MyObject[] objects;

    MyCompositeObjects(MyObjects... objects) {
        this.objects = Arrays.copyOf(objects,objects.length);
        // or just: this.objects = objects; ?
    }

    // ...
}
```

The constructor may be called with a single `MyObject[]` argument, which may change later, and if I do not copy the array in the constructor those changes will apply to the member variable `objects` as well, right? However, if the constructor is called with several `MyObject`s, there is no other reference to the array* to change it later outside the class, so I could assign it directly. Can I tell inside the constructor (or, generally, any function that takes varargs) how it was called?

*nb: Is there a specific name for this? Is it simply an anonymous array?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, you can't. It's meant to be entirely transparent - this code:

```
new MyCompositeObjects(a, b);
```

is exactly equivalent to

```
new MyCompositeObjects(new MyObjects[] { a, b });
```

If you can *trust* your callers to do the right thing, you could always create two static methods and make the constructor private:

```
public static MyCompositeObjects createWithCopy(MyObjects[] values) {
    return new MyCompositeObjects(Arrays.copyOf(values, values.length));
}

public static MyCompositeObjects createWithoutCopy(MyObjects... values) {
    return new MyCompositeObjects(values);
}

private MyCompositeObjects(MyObjects[] values) {
    this.objects = values;
}
```

Note how the "with copy" version doesn't use varargs, which should help users to use the right version.

Answer (score 4):

The only way to know is to parse the code.  This is because varargs is basicaly a compile time feature and doesn't change how the program runs.

If in doubt, I would always copy the array. Unless you know this will be a performance issue.

BTW: You can do the following.

```
MyCompositeObjects(MyObjects o1, MyObjects... objects) {

MyCompositeObjects(MyObjects[] objects) {
```

However, this likely to do the opposite of what you want.

Another option is to use a static factory.

```
private MyCompositeObjects(MyObjects[] objects) {
   this.objects = objects;
}

MyCompositeObjects create(MyObjects... objects) {
    return new MyCompositeObjects(objects.close());
}

MyCompositeObjects createNotCopied(MyObjects... objects) {
    return new MyCompositeObjects(objects, false);
}
```

Use the more cumbersome method name for the less safe version.  This means if a method is chosen without much thought, the safe version is more likely to be used.

Comment: There are problems in your static factory example.  The "copy" boolean isn't a constructor argument, and the call to objects.close().